# Specializations of std::size and std::empty do not match the template

Tags: c++, templates, std, c++17

I want to extend the `std` namespace by adding template specializations of `std::size` and `std::empty` for my custom containers (outside the `std`).

I have two questions:

1. Why are [`std::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) and [`std::empty`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/empty) `constexpr`? As far as I am aware of only the size and the emptiness of `std::array` and arrays on the stack can be known at compile time which is not the case for other containers such as `std::vector` and `std::map`. So how could `std::size` and `std::empty` even work when substituting a `std::vector` as template parameter for instance?
2. I tried to extend the `std` with template specializations of `std::size` and `std::empty` for my custom containers, but the compiler could not deduce the specialized template method. Could someone explain what I do wrong?

**My code** [[Try it online in Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uyu4Ni6UFAm68961)]:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

namespace dummy {
    struct Widget {
        bool IsEmpty() const noexcept { return m_v.empty(); }
        size_t GetSize() const noexcept { return m_v.size(); }
        std::vector< int > m_v;
    };
}

namespace std {

    template<>
    constexpr auto empty(const dummy::Widget &widget)
        -> decltype(widget.IsEmpty()) {

        return widget.IsEmpty();
    }

    template<>
    constexpr auto size(const dummy::Widget &widget)
        -> decltype(widget.GetSize()) {

        return widget.GetSize();
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector< int > ints;
    std::size(ints);
}
```

**Output**:

```
prog.cc:15:17: error: no function template matches function template specialization 'empty'
        constexpr auto empty(const dummy::Widget &widget)
                       ^
/opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/iterator:1843:16: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Cont = dummy::Widget]: no member named 'empty' in 'dummy::Widget'
constexpr auto empty(const _Cont& __c)
               ^
/opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/iterator:1850:16: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'type-parameter-0-0 const[_Np]' against 'const dummy::Widget'
constexpr bool empty(const _Tp (&)[_Sz]) noexcept { return false; }
               ^
/opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/iterator:1854:16: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'initializer_list<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'const dummy::Widget &'
constexpr bool empty(initializer_list<_Ep> __il) noexcept { return __il.size() == 0; }
               ^
prog.cc:22:17: error: no function template matches function template specialization 'size'
        constexpr auto size(const dummy::Widget &widget)
                       ^
/opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/iterator:1832:16: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Cont = dummy::Widget]: no member named 'size' in 'dummy::Widget'
constexpr auto size(const _Cont& __c)
               ^
/opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/iterator:1839:18: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'type-parameter-0-0 const[_Np]' against 'const dummy::Widget'
constexpr size_t size(const _Tp (&)[_Sz]) noexcept { return _Sz; }
```

Comment: `size` and `empty` potentially can work at compile time when used with array views.

Comment: Specializing function templates are generally considered poor form, as they don't participate in overload resolution. There even is a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0551r1.pdf) to altogether prohibit specializing templates in the std namespace. Rather, the common idiom is to provide `size()` and `empty()` implementations in the same namespace as your user defined types, and let ADL take care of finding those definitions. Within template functions, you should never explicitely call `std::size`, but rather do `using std::size; x = size(y);` to make use of ADL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are `std::size` and `std::empty` `constexpr`?

For function templates, `constexpr` only means the resulting function will be `constexpr` if possible. It doesn't mean it will be `constexpr` for all instantiations. In the case of `std::vector`, that means that that particular instantiation of `std::size` will not be.

> I tried to extend the std with template specializations of `std::size` and `std::empty` for my custom containers, but the compiler could not deduce the specialized template method.

That's because the versions of `std::size` and `std::empty` you're attempting to provide specialisations for have a different return type. The standard return type is `decltype(c.size())` / `decltype(c.empty())`. You don't provide `size()` or `empty()` member functions, so this cannot possibly work. Just use the standard names.

Answer (score 2):

> 2. I tried to extend the std with template specializations of std::size and std::empty for my custom containers, but the compiler could not deduce the specialized template method. Could someone explain what I do wrong?

`std::size` signature is:

```
template <class C>
constexpr auto size( const C& c ) -> decltype(c.size());
```

your one is different:

```
template<>
constexpr auto size(const dummy::Widget &widget)
    -> decltype(widget.GetSize());
```

The `decltype(..)` content is different, you do SFINAE on different method.

So your function isn't not a specialization.

So, unless you add a `widget::size()` declaration in your class, you cannot specialize that function in `std`.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to extend `std::size` is not via specialization.

Instead you should define a free function `size` in the same namespace as your type (optionally as an inline `friend`).

Then

```
using std::size;
std::cout << size( your_container ) << "\n";
```

works; and `your_container` replaced with a C array or a `std` container also works (in generic code).

The requirement to `using std::size` is annoying.  You can work around it:

```
namespace notstd {
  namespace adl_size {
    using std::size;
    template<class T>
    constexpr auto get_size(T const& t)
    noexcept( noexcept( size(t) ) )
    ->decltype( size(t) )
    { return size(t); }
  }
  template<class T>
  constexpr auto size( T const& t )
  noexcept( noexcept( ::notstd::adl_size::get_size(t) ) )
  -> decltype( ::notstd::adl_size::get_size(t) )
  { return ::notstd::adl_size::get_size(t); }
}
```

now `notstd::size( vector )` and `notstd::size( your_container )` and `notstd::size( some_array )` all work, and no need to explicitly add `using std::size` before using it.